# XPath 最初に見つかったノードのみを処理する

Tags: xpath, xsl, xslt

以下のような xsl の場合，最初に見つかった要素のみを処理したい場合に
XPath はどのような式になりますでしょうか？

例えば  xsl:copy-of select="$v//p/@*" とすると，配下すべての p 要素の属性がコピーされてしまいます。最初の要素のみを処理したいのです。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" 
version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="v">
    <a>
        <p att1="a" att2="b" >
            <p att3="c"> 
                <p >
                </p>
            </p>
        </p>
    </a>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <p>
        <xsl:copy-of select="????"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

期待する結果

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><p att1="a" att2="b" />
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$v/descendant::p[1]/@*`。

`$v//p[1]` だと意味が異なるので、`$v/descendant::p[1]` にします。

例示だと `$v` は document node ですが、もし `$v` が `as="element()"` になることがあるのなら、`$v/descendant-or-self::p[1]` がお求めのものになるかもしれません。

Comment: `$v//p[1]` だと、どのように意味が異なりますでしょうか？

Comment: (A) `$v//p[1]` を省略せずに記すと、`$v/descendant-or-self::node()/child::p[1]` である。
(B) `$v/descendant-or-self::node()/child::p[1]` において、predicate の優先順位は高いので、`[1]` は `child::p` に作用する。
(A) (B) より、`$v//p[1]` は、`$v/descendant-or-self::node()` である node 各々から `child::p[1]` を選択する。例示の `$v` では、すべての `p` が親から見て `child::p[1]` なので、すべての `p` を選択する。
…で、合ってるでしょうか？

Comment: 私の方は知識不足で両者の違いの合点が行かないので別途質問を起こしてみます．